# What is the significance of type in elastic search?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

So I wish to dump my rdb to elasticsearch to utilize search capabilities.
Below example snippet shows how to index an item with attributes.
I am envisioning there will be close to 1m records eventually.

```
$params = array();
$params['body']  = array(
  'name' => 'Ash Ketchum',
  'age' => 10,
  'badges' => 8 
);

$params['index'] = 'pokemon';
$params['type']  = 'pokemon_trainer';

$result = $client->index($params);
```

I have a few questions here.

1. is `index` eqv to database in rdb?
2. is `type` eqv of table in rdb?
3. I will be fuzzy searching `body->name` field, is this the correct implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is index eqv to database in rdb?

It can be or not. Usually, I don't recommend mirroring a DB database with an index. Elasticsearch usually likes de-normalized data ;-), rather than the usual relational DB with inner keys.

> is type eqv of table in rdb?

NO. The `type` is a convenient way to do field filters. The `_type` itself is just a field in the index.

> I will be fuzzy searching body->name field, is this the correct implementation?

I don't know what you mean by that, but yes you can search on fields. I suggest first going over [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) (it helps a lot) and then look at the [php one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/index.html).

Comment: so if I don't need type, then I  shouldn't put it there?

Comment: No, you need a type. But a table in a database doesn't mean you need to create a type for each. You can create 2 indices for 10 tables, or 2 indices for 2 tables. Each index can have one type or more. What I was trying to say, basically, don't mirror the DB in Elasticsearch by using `index->database` and `type->table` analogy. Do, please, read at least the introductory part of Elasticsearch documentation. You will understand way better these concepts. Don't blindly start using ES.

Comment: I have read it once, it doesn't really tell much about what index and type are. I will read it once more... hm..

Comment: The documentation revolves around the idea of associating RDB with ES as index->db and type->type. But in real world this doesn't really apply. And the ES documentation will, most likely, be re-worded regarding types and indices association with RDBs.

Comment: thank you so much. I have one last question : say I have indexed object called `foo`. `foo` didn't change, and I ran index again. Is es smart enough to not reindex that again? or does it reindex regardless of the data.

Comment: It depends how you index :-). If you do `POST /test_index/test_type/1
{"test":"x"}` and then again the same command, the document with id `1` will be updated, not indexed in a new document. By default, the document with the same id will be updated.